# Assign system variables provided by the variable names in an array

Tags: bash, shell

There is a bunch of variables to assign value. I was able to do it in a stupid way by copy-pasting the same piece of code, and then change the part that is different.
For example, I want to do the following:
export country="US"
export city="LA"

The stupid way, with a user-input interface, is:

```
printf "\nPlease assign country$ \n" ;  
if [[ $country == nil ]] ; then
    printf "Current value is nil\n"
else
    printf "Current value is: $country\n"
fi ;
printf "country: " ;
read -e -i $country country_
export country=$country_
```

And for city, I just search-replace "country" with "city" and past the code, which is stupid, but works.
Now, I want to improve the readability, and also maintainability, of the code, buy putting the variable names in a list and then iterate over this list.
The half-worked-out code, after googling is:

```
declare -a var_list=("country" "city")
for var in ${var_list[*]}
    do
        printf "\nPlease assign $var \n" ;  
        if [[ ${!var} == nil ]] ; then
            printf "Current value is nil\n"
        else
            printf "Current value is: ${!var}\n"
        fi ;
        printf "${bold}$var: ${normal}" ;
        read -e -i ${!var} {$var_}
        export $var={$var_}
    done
```

The following 2 lines of codes are still not correct to do what I want them to do:

```
read -e -i ${!var} {$var_}
export $var={$var_}
```

I would like to get some help on that.

Comment: `GUI interface` - there is no a graphical interface here `nil` -  the string "nil" doesn't have any special meaning in bash, why do you check for it?

Comment: `export country=country_` - why do you export a variable named `country` with the string `country_` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk By GUI interface, I actually mean the "read" command that provides some sort of user interaction. And 'nil' is to check for the case that the the variable is not set.

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right. What I wanted to do is country=$country_

Comment: 1. An unset variable expands to nothing. You can use some  parameter expansions to check if a variable is set/unset. Search stackoverflow for a post about that, it's explained there. If `[[ $country == nil ]]` is true then `country` is set and it is set to the string `nil`. 2. GUI is Graphical User Interface, ie. you can "click" on it. You are writing a Command Line Interface - CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function from it and pass variable name to it:

```
get() {
        # descriptive variable names
        local var previousvalue
        var="$1"
        previousvalue="${!1}"

        # superfluous, servers as a documentation
        # The string "$1" should be a global variable
        declare -g "$var"

        # Asking the real questions:
        printf "\nPlease assign $var \n"
        printf "Current value is '$previousvalue'\n"
        read -e -p "$1: " -i "$previousvalue" "$var"
}


declare -a var_list=("country" "city")
for i in "${var_list[@]}"; do           # or just `for i in country city; do`
        get "$i"
done

echo
echo "country=$country"
echo "city=$city"
```

example exeuction:

```
Please assign country 
Current value is ''
country: Poland

Please assign city 
Current value is ''
city: Warsaw

country=Poland
city=Warsaw
```

Notes:

- Don't use `for var in ${var_list[*]}`, it will improperly handle array elements with spaces inside them. Do `for var in "${var_list[@]}"`. The `"${...[@]}"` will properly quote and pass all variables.
- The `export $var={$var_}` line exports the variable named after expansion `$var` to the string consisting of `{` the expansion of `var_` variable and `}`. I guess you don't want to include the `{` `}` in the value. I guess you wanted to write `"${var}_"` or `"${var_}"` - the `{` have to be after `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you avoid resorting to variable indirection and use a function instead :

```
display_and_read() {
  local item_type="$1" previous_value="$2"
  printf "\nPlease assign $item_type$ \n" ;  
  if [[ $previous_value == nil ]] ; then
    printf "Current value is nil\n"
  else
    printf "Current value is: $previous_value\n"
  fi ;
  printf "$item_type: " ;
}

display_and_read "country" "$country"
read -e -i $country country_
export country=$country_

display_and_read "city" "$city"
read -e -i $city city_
export city=$city_
```

Comment: How would you put "country" and "city" in a list and loop through it?

Comment: I wouldn't, as the amount of repetition is now minimal and having either to use variable indirection or handle separately a variable content and its name would in my opinion not be worth it if you only have two variables to iterate over. That said, Kamil's answer seems like a good solution if you really want to loop over your variables.